# Selecting only elements with specific attributes from Java List

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

So lets say I have a list, `List<MyObject>`, and a class MyObject as such:

```
public class MyObject {
    Type t;
}
```

Where 't' is a non-unique identifier. How would I select all elements from my list with a specific value for t? For my purpose I am trying to return a count of how many objects in the list have a specific value for t.

I am assuming there is some clean way of doing this in Java without using an explicit loop?

Comment: `without using an explicit loop?` What is wrong with looping over the List?

Comment: If Java has something like `Comparator` that can be used here I would like to know. I am sure that will use a loop, but consider it for the sake of knowledge :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Streams are your friend:

```
List<MyObject> list = ...;
long count = list.stream().filter(e -> e.getT().equals(<specific value>)).count();
```

You would of course need a way to access `t`, here I use `getT()` as an example.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Java 8 use simple iteration as following:

```
int count(List<MyObject> list, Type x) {
  int cnt = 0;
  for(MyObject obj: list) {
    if(obj.getT() == x) cnt++; 
  }
  return cnt;
}
```